# Is it a bad idea to force JVM reload of "java.library.path"?

Tags: java, path, applet

**Scenario:**

I have an applet that must use a .dll.
That .dll MUST live on PATH.
In order to get the .dll on PATH, through the applet, the user running the browser MUST have administrative rights (Usually done as right-click icon Run As Administrator...).

**Problem:**

I would like to remove the need of having to gain administrative privelages.

**The bad idea**
I would like to have the applet save the file somewhere inside the users home directory.  I would like to add that path to PATH.  Appearently, it can be done via:

```
    System.setProperty("java.library.path", <new path>);

    try {
        // this forces JVM to reload "java.library.path" property 
        Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" ); 
        fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true ); 
        fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        init_failure = true;
    }
```

**Question**

Is it a bad idea to force the JVM to do this?  Is this using undocumented methods/is it just plain hacky?

**Other bits**

Because this is an applet, I can not specify java.library.path via -D option, correct ?

This code is in an intranet.  Not intended for the average internet tough guy.

Comment: Wouldn't we all like to "remove the need of having to gain administrative privileges"...

Comment: Yes, it is a bad idea to do it this way. This relies on implementation details of the `ClassLoader` that is being used. This might not work in a future version of the JRE, or a JRE implementation by other vendors; there is no guarantee that the particular `ClassLoader` implementation being used has a field named `sys_paths`.

Comment: The solution is ugly, but possibly the least ugly solution. ;)

Comment: @Jesper ok thanks that is what i was afraid of.  No point in doing this if I may have to revert back at some point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

field.setAccessible( true ) is always hacky and undocumented. It changes a private field! Maybe you get lucky and it works for all supported JVM's, and it doesn't change anytime in the future.

I also worry about what would happen if the JVM found and loaded a version of your dll in the previous java.library.path for some reason, before you changed the path. I guess it would keep the loaded version, and not load the new one.

If you work in a controlled environment you might ignore these issues, but I'd encourage you to find another solution. E.g. tell users to remote install the dll with a simple installer.